# How I can create project and VM instance after getting admin access for compute engine in google cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-messaging, google-compute-engine, google-ima

I have got admin access for compute engine on google cloud by my boss. It is a company account for all of us. But, I am not able to access anything from google cloud SDK shell or with GUI of google cloud. I have searched a lot and there is nothing on this from Google in the documentation. I even have not received an e-mail saying that I got an admin level access. What could go wrong? How can I access the compute engine? What is the problem with this?

Comment: Open a command prompt / shell. Execute `gcloud init`. https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing

Comment: I already did that and after that, the output was like `Settings from your current configuration [my-project1] are:
core:
  account: mail-id 
  disable_usage_reporting: 'False'
  project: my-project

Pick configuration to use:
 [1] Re-initialize this configuration [my-project1] with new settings
 [2] Create a new configuration
 [3] Switch to and re-initialize existing configuration: [default]
Please enter your numeric choice:` 
What to do with this because this is project from my personal account and not company aacount.

Comment: Have your boss double check to make sure there was no spelling mistake when he gave you permission

Comment: Also run 'gcloud auth login' to check which user is currently logged in to the SDK

Comment: Use `gcloud auth list` to see the Google Accounts that are setup. Can you post a redacted copy of the email from Google. I have never received or seen one like that. In Google IAM, the word `admin` is not used. It is more likely `project owner`.

Comment: First thing, can yo log into the projectID where your boss give yo access trough the [google cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com)